# Syntax error when using screen with ssh and remote gawk

Tags: bash, shell, awk, ssh, gnu-screen

I need to run the following command in a bash script.

The command needs to be run inside a GNU screen so I can see the progress. So the command needs to be in quotes, but because of that I am having problems with the syntax and the code isn't running properly.

I have a file in a remote server called `textfile.txt`. It looks like this.

The command gawk command runs fine on its own.

```
test-server-name 1
test-server-name 2
test-server-name 3
...
test-server-name 23
test-server-name 24
...
```

I run a screen command together with an ssh command that runs a gawk command to modify a line in the text file, in this case, it should look for `test-server-name-1` and add a `0` next to it like this.

```
test-server-name 1 0
test-server-name 2
test-server-name 3
...
test-server-name 23
test-server-name 24
...
```

This is what my script looks like in my local server.

```
localhostname='test-server-name-1'
counter=1
function='textfile'

screen -dmS $counter "ssh -i ~/.ssh/ssh-key username@masteripaddress 'gawk -i inplace -v n='0' -v s='${localhostname}-${function}' '$1 == s { $2 = n } 1' /home/master/Documents/${function}.txt';exec bash;"
```

But when I run it, the script runs, and I get this error in the attached screen,

```
gawk: cmd. line:1: ==
gawk: cmd. line:1: ^ syntax error
```

How do I fix it? What characters need to be escaped

Comment: You have nested single quotes

Comment: is there a way to fix this ? im getting confused with the syntax as well

Comment: try: `screen -dmS $counter "ssh -i ~/.ssh/ssh-key username@masteripaddress \"gawk -i inplace -v n='0' -v s=$localhostname '$1 == s { $2 = n } 1' /home/master/Documents/${function}.txt\";exec bash;"`

Comment: hey man I m getting the same error, I modified the code a bit please take another look, the s= command needs to be in quotes I think

Comment: shell, screen, ssh, gawk -- you need to handle nested quotation for all of them. dont do this. put a shell script on remote side and call it via ssh.

Comment: why `exec bash` in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>(Don't do this. It'll be much easier if you put a script on remote side.)</sup>

Just give you an example (with `\`-style escaping):

```
[STEP 101] $ # to run an awk command locally
[STEP 102] $ title='THE SUM: '
[STEP 103] $ printf '%d\n' {1..10} | awk -v title="$title" '{ sum += $1 } END { print title sum }'
THE SUM: 55
[STEP 104] $
[STEP 105] $ # to run the awk command thru screen + ssh
[STEP 106] $ # added 'sleep 1' for easy watching
[STEP 107] $ title='THE SUM: '
[STEP 108] $ screen -c /dev/null -m ssh 127.0.0.1 printf\ \'%d\\n\'\ \{1..10\}\ \|\ awk\ -v\ title=\'"$title"\'\ \'\{\ sum\ +=\ \$1\ \}\ END\ \{\ print\ title\ sum\ \}\'\;\ sleep\ 1
THE SUM: 55
[screen is terminating]
[STEP 109] $
```

Comment: but the local server needs to be the cause of the change in the remote server.